# Is there any option available to set session authorization paramater in liquibase property file?

Tags: liquibase

I am using `Liquibase-3.5.3-bin`, with DB2 v10.5(windows).

I am unable to set session authorization. Is there any property through which I can set this value. Without this, I am getting privilege issue, while running my changeset, that includes table creation.

> Unexpected error running Liquibase: DB2 SQL Error: SQLCODE=-551, SQLSTATE=42501, SQLERRMC=****;CREATE TABLE;DBM.DUMMY_LQ_001, DRIVER=3.62.56 [Failed SQL: CREATE TABLE DBM.Dummy_lq_001 (ATR1 INTEGER, ATR2 INTEGER) IN TABSPC1]

Answer (score 0):

Liquibase is based on a JDBC Connection. The DB2 JDBC Driver seems to allow to set this information on the URL. See this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22377548/332248) for reference.

So you should be able to set this in your `liquibase.properties` file or wherever you specify you DB connection settings for liquibase.